# How to enable LyX forward search with okular

Tags: lyx, forward-inverse-search, okular

The title says it. The instructions in http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX no longer works for forward search. I think the PDF command: 
`okular --unique "file:$$o#src:$$n $$t"`
is no longer working for new TeX software.
Inverse search is workable though.

Comment: how did you get the inverse search to work.. i can't even get that.. using windows 7 lyx 2.0.5

Comment: I am not using windows. Suggest that you start a new question to have it answered.

Answer (score 4):

It works in my machine (openSUSE) with the following options.
In LyX, `Tools` > `Preferences` > `Output` > `General` > `PDF command` under `Forward search`:

```
okular --unique "file:$$o#src:$$n $$f"
```

or

```
okular --unique "$$o#src:$$n $$f"
```

Both worked for me. Hope this solves your problem.
And `$$f` option only works with LyX 2.0.5+.

Comment: I just edited the LyX wiki as well.

Comment: In LyX "Document settings... > Output" the default for "Custom Macro" seems to be `\usepackage[active]{srcltx}` rather than `\synctex=-1` as stated in the LyX wiki. For LyX 2.0.5.1 with Okular 0.14.3 (on openSUSE), it seems necessary to set "Custom Macro" to `\synctex=-1`. Then forward and inverse search are working.

Comment: you should maybe also change your pdf file type opener in LyX to `okular --unique` so that okular does not throw up a new tab on each forward search.